# Spring junit error single matching bean but found 2

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-test

I have a test class, and have created a java config class to use with this class.. But im having issues as other tests seem to throw up found two instances of bean in configuration...

my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestConfiguration.class)
public class ListenerTest {

// various tests.. just basic stuff..

}

@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {        


    @Bean
    public MyListsner ListenerImpl() {
        return Mockito.mock(MyListsner .class);
    }

}
```

Now for this test class passes fine when i use a mock as above. My other test classes seem to fail and they are as follows:

test class which fails...

This class throws the error

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=GeneratorTestConfiguration.class)
@Transactional
public class GeneratorTest {

  // various tests

}
```

Main config

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        BaseConfiguration.class,
        CoreBaseConfiguration.class
    })
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={
    "com.persistence.repository"
})
@ComponentScan({     // where the components are
    "com.tests"
})

public class GeneratorTestConfiguration {

}
```

I dont know why, when i add listener mock to the above class ListenerTest, the toher tests fail, as im being specific in those classes to use the relevant configuration when autowiring.

Comment: anyone, got any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems the bean was defined twice.